# API is called automatically after clicking on an element in Cypress

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-intercept

**Given the following code**:

```js
  cy.intercept('POST', 'get_time_slots', { fixture: data }).as('getTimeslotList');

  cy.get('input.datepicker').type("2024-01-10").trigger('change');

  cy.get("checkbox#flexCheckDefault").click()
```

**Explaination**:

- The `cy.get('input.datepicker').type("2024-01-10").trigger('change')` command will trigger the call to the `get_time_slots` API, which returns a list of timeslot - which is mocked by a fixture file

  > Note: Changing the date value is the only way to trigger the api call
- The `cy.get("checkbox#flexCheckDefault").click()` command will show the timeslot list to the UI, but the weird things are:

  - It also calls the `get_time_slots` API 1 more time
  - This behavior **doesn't happen** if the checkbox is *clicked manually via the UI*

[image]

---

**Components source code:**

**Date picker**

```
<input 
   placeholder="Select date" type="date"
   class="form-control date-input-custom datepicker"
   t-att-max="state.maxDate"
   t-att-disabled="this.checkDatePickerDisable()"
   t-att-min="state.todayLabel"
   t-on-change="(e) => this.onSelectDate(e.target.value)"
   t-att-value="state.appointment.booking_date" />
```

**The checkbox:**

```
<input
   type="checkbox" value="" 
   id="flexCheckDefault"
   t-on-input="this.showSlot" />
```

(*I got the same issue when using `.check()` instead of `click()`*)

Has anyone experienced this issue before, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Don't know why, but `click()` fires many events (but not `change`) see [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Command-Log). But with checkbox `.check()` is more usual action command. Do you have component source?

Comment: I got the same issue when using `.check()` instead of `click()` and 

Please check the original question for the brief source for the components (as I couldn't post it in the comment section)

Comment: The second click to `#flexCheckDefault` must do something - what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Briana
By default, the app only displays the enabled time slots, but when #flexCheckDefault is clicked, it also shows the disabled time slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that the double-up of `change` event occurs because the app is already set up to fire `change` when the element loses focus.

This would occur ***when the second element is clicked***, see the docs for `.click()`  at [Focus](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Focus)

> **Focus**
>
> Focus is given to the first focusable element
> For example, clicking a  inside of a  gives the focus to the button...

If this is true, you can omit the `.trigger('change')` and add a `.blur()` instead.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', 'get_time_slots', { fixture: data }).as('getTimeslotList');

cy.get('input.datepicker').type("2024-01-10")  // see docs - unsafe to chain 
cy.get('input.datepicker').blur()

cy.wait('@getTimeslotList')  // you have this but have not shown it in the test code

cy.get("checkbox#flexCheckDefault").click()
```

[Docs .type()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type) says

> It is unsafe to chain further commands that rely on the subject after `.type()`

This is particularly true if the `change` event is fired by the app - the DOM is likely to re-render. To be safe, issue another `cy.get('input.datepicker')` for the next action.

Comment: That was a great answer!!! 
I changed it to `blur()` and the API is no longer called 2nd time.
The only confusing thing is about the order of the execution: 
- **With change**: the API is called BEFORE the wait() command.
- **With blur**: the API is called AFTER the `wait()` command. 

https://prnt.sc/GM4GEgKK_K-u

Comment: I've think I've seen that too but it's not registered as an anomaly, but clearly would be better if Cypress logged in correct sequence. Possibly due to event listeners which will only fire when the current running thread finishes, or maybe in a React app it's hooks that are processing in the app background.